# How can i get Population Density as a polygon layer?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0

I have some points (population) and using function Kernel Density i have calculated population density, then i reclassified the information. Now i would like to use the population density data in "union"function but the problem is that the input data has to be polygons! How can I solve this problem? I'm using ArcGIS10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert your raster data to vector (polygons) using the [Raster to Polygon (Conversion)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001200000008000000) tool.